# Independency of X,Y given that $X^2$, $Y^2$ are independent.

Tags: random-variables, independence

Let $X$, $Y$ be random variables with positive probability density on every real number $x$.

($pdf_X(x)>0$, $pdf_Y(x)>0$ for every real $x$)

If $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are idependent, is $X$ and $Y$ also independent?

I found a counter-example, but it did not satisfied the positive pdf condition.

I'm not sure whether it is true or not.

Comment: I don't know the context of the question. But it might be interesting to say that if the condition was $f_X(x)=0$ for $x<0$ (and the same for $Y$), which says that $P(X\ge0)=1$ and $P(Y\ge0)=1$, then if $X^2$ and $Y^2$ are independent, so are $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W$ be a fair coin flip, and let $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ be independent standard normal random variables.

If $W$ is heads, let $X=|Z_1|$ and $Y=|Z_2|$. Otherwise if $W$ is tails, let $X=-|Z_1|$ and $Y=-|Z_2|$.

Then $X^2=Z_1^2$ and $Y^2=Z_2^2$ are independent because $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ are. However, $X$ and $Y$ have the same sign, so they are not independent.